# HashTable en el estado de un Servicio Web

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, hashmap

Diseñando un servicio web que usa un login y que mantiene todos los datos de los usuarios y sus contraseñas en memoria (no usa ninguna base de datos) me han surgido dudas a la hora de poder asegurar un nivel de eficiencia decente:

En primer lugar, qué estructura de datos elegir para guardar dicha información. Si bien creo que un `HashMap` sería una buena opción, donde los usernames serían las claves y el resto de la información (o solo la password) serían los valores, me gustaría saber si existen otras estructuras de datos que encajen mejor.

Además, en el caso concreto del `HashMap`, ¿sería mejor utilizar `separateChainnig` o `LinearProbing` como estrategia de resolución de conflictos? En el caso de `separateChaining` nos enfrentamos a que una de las listas de los "huecos" del hashMap fuera muy larga y la complejidad ascendiera a orden lineal en el peor caso, pero con `LinearProbing` podrían darse muchos rehashes.

¿Qué opináis?

Answer (score 1):

La estructura `HashMap` ya cuenta con mecanismos de auto size para no caer en búsquedas lineales como indicas. Esto lo explico en otra respuesta: [¿Como funciona HashSet internamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6128/227), donde, en resumen, un `HashMap` tiene un arreglo de nodos, y estos nodos pueden formar una lista enlazada o un árbol rojo negro, de acuerdo a la cantidad de elementos que posee ese hash. Al conocer esto, puedes comprender que no es necesario aplicar separate chaining ni linear probing para resolver tu problema.

Puesto que quieres almacenar la información en memoria, más bien te diría que necesitas considerar otras cosas al momento de elegir la estructura apropiada:

1. Si solo necesitas pre cargar los usuarios y contraseñas y luego tu servicio será únicamente de consulta para el login, entonces te conviene utilizar `HashMap`.
2. Si adicional a las búsquedas necesitas agregar elementos a tu estructura, te recomiendo que utilices `ConcurrentHashMap` en lugar de `HashMap` puesto que la primera ya tiene soporte incluido para múltiples transacciones en paralelo, mientras que la segunda no lo posee y puede que te salga un error de `ConcurrentModificationException` en tiempo de ejecución.
3. Quizás necesites aplicar otras políticas a esta estructura, así que te recomiendo que en lugar de crear y adaptar la estructura manualmente a lo que necesitas, evalúes utilizar un caché como EhCache o Hazelcast o quizás un base de datos NoSQL clave valor como Hazelcast o Redis, los cuales son productos más completos y que proveen muchas más funcionalidades que estar tratando de automatizar manualmente.

Answer (score 0):

Me huele de lejos a [optimización prematura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura). 
En el 99.9999% de los casos es irrelevante preguntarse por los detalles de  funcionamiento interno de un `HashMap`. Y creo que es tu caso.

Más debería preocuparte cómo es que vas a tener un mapa de usuarios=>claves en memoria... esas claves están no encriptadas? De dónde provienen? 
En general, es peligroso tener las claves almacenadas (en base de datos, archivos o memoria), lo recomendado es tener sólo un [hash](http://www.lnds.net/blog/lnds/2005/8/25/usando-one-way-hash).