# HashSet como funciona exactamente

Tags: java, hashmap

Supongamos que tengo este main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HashSet<Persona> conjuntoPersonas= new HashSet<>();
            Persona p1 = new Persona("Jose", "1");
            Persona p2 = new Persona("Ivan", "2");
            Persona p3 = new Persona("Alex", "2");
            System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p1));
            System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p2));
            System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p3));
            System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.size());
    }
}
```

Y esta clase Persona:

```
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String dni;

    public Persona(String nombre, String dni) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Persona persona = (Persona) o;
        return this.dni.equals(persona.getDni());
    }



    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

}
```

Yo tenia entendido que cuando lo ejecutase deberia imprimir:

```
true  // lo añade al conjunto
true  // lo añade al conjunto
false // no lo añade al conjunto por que entiende que esta repetido 
2     // imprime dos por que el tercer elemento no lo añade
```

Sin embargo obtengo

```
true
true
true
3
```

Y en el depurador veo que si que me lo añade aunque este repetido.Alguien me puede ayudar a entender por que no obtengo el comportamiento deseado???

Comment: Quiero aclarar que aunque la respuesta de @Einer es perfecta, esta pregunta tiene un [duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6124/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-hashset-internamente) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para comprobar que 2 objetos son iguales, tienen que cumplirse 2 condiciones:

1. Que el metodo `equals` returne true
2. Si el metodo `equals(object)` returna true, entonces se entiende que el metodo `hashCode()` tambien returna true.

Hagamos una prueba con tu codigo y verifiquemos si ambas son correctas:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Persona> conjuntoPersonas= new HashSet<>();
        Persona p1 = new Persona("Jose", "1");
        Persona p2 = new Persona("Ivan", "2");
        Persona p3 = new Persona("Alex", "2");


        System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p2)); // true
        System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p3)); // true
        System.out.println(p2.hashCode()); // 366712642
        System.out.println(p3.hashCode()); // 1829164700

    }
```

Como notas, el metodo `add()` returna true en ambos casos, pero el metodo `hasCode()` returna resultados diferentes por lo que `HashSet` entiende que son objetos diferentes aunque `equals` returne `true`.

Tienes que sobre escribir el metodo `hashCode()` de la clase `Persona` y returnar el hashCode del objeto con el cual estas comparando, que en este caso seria `dni`:

```
public static class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private String dni;

    public Persona(String nombre, String dni) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Persona persona = (Persona) o;
        return this.dni.equals(persona.getDni());
    }

    // sobre escribimos el metodo hashCode() y returnanos el hashCode() del dni ya que es el
    // campo principal para comprar
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getDni().hashCode();
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

}
```

Si probamos ahora nos dara el resultado deseado:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Persona> conjuntoPersonas= new HashSet<>();
        Persona p1 = new Persona("Jose", "1");
        Persona p2 = new Persona("Ivan", "2");
        Persona p3 = new Persona("Alex", "2");


        System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p2)); // true
        System.out.println(conjuntoPersonas.add(p3)); // false
        System.out.println(p2.hashCode()); // 50
        System.out.println(p3.hashCode()); // 50

    }
```

Ahora bien, hay que tener precaución al momento de sobre escribir este metodo. Si deseas mas informacion dale una mirada a la pregunta [¿Equals y HashCode? Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/equals-y-hashcode-java) que explica muy bien el tema.